# Customizing Select And Input tags, IE version looks awful

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I'm trying to make a search bar, category select, and search query.
I'm trying to make them look both the same, same size font.
But I don't want the options to look the same size as the select tag

http://jsfiddle.net/gg8RD/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="searchInput" style="postion:relative">
            <select onchange="document.getElementById('category').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
                <optgroup>
                    <option>Cat 1</option>
                    <option>Cat 2</option>
                    <option>Cat 3</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <input id="category" style="postion:absolute width:300px" placeholder="Choose A Cateogry" value="Choose A Category">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="searchInput">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search Query">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
div.searchInput input {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
div.searchInput select {
    border:none;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
     height:38px;
    width:300px;
    color:transparent;position:absolute; 
     background-color:transparent;
}
div.searchInput {
    color:black;
    background-color: white;
}

div.searchInput {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:300px; border: 
    1px #000000 solid;}

body {
    font-family:Helvetica Neue,Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #666;
    background:rgba(9,9,9,0.6);
}
`
```

Is what I've come up with and it's around the style and size I want.
But it looks terrible in Internet Explorer.

Why is this? How can I get them to look the same? And if not: What's my next path?

Comment: You should post the css as well, the fiddle may not be available in the future. And there needs to be a semi-colon between `absolute` and `width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each browser has its own default css-rules and behaviours, this is particularly apparent with form elements.

You can either use a css-reset to attempt to equalize all the browser-defaults, or add a number of other rules to your css (line-height, font settings, margins, etc.) - effectively creating your own css-reset rules.

Personally, I would not attempt to make them look *identical* in all browsers - this is not possible. I would just test them in the different browsers and make sure that they are presentable (that they work) in each.

You may find it useful to use:

```
select, option, input { font-family: inherit; }
```

and perhaps `inherit` for other rules, but attempting to format option elements is problematic.

[This article](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200701/styling_form_controls_with_css_revisited/) further discusses the problems with using css to style form elements.

Comment: BTW You haven't created any rules currently for the `options`. Unfortunately, you may find the rules you add applied inconsistently across browsers. Option elements don't inherit font or colour properties from their parent-select element, but from system styles.

Comment: Well I set my rules for my optgroup, I'll try setting them for options. I'm not trying to make it look identical, but view that in IE and it's not presentable at all.